# Logstash unable to mutate text log

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I am sending below log file from filbeat to Logstash. The below is the output from filbeat to Logstash

`\u001b[m\u001b[32m[2019-12-02T17:30:09,995] INFO  - [http-nio-8080-exec-9:40] {client_ip=13.232.113.45, request_id=8D9383C6E4FD40EC90324627F8EF839C} [filter.RequestAndResponseLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal:113]   Response body: {\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"success\"}"`

I want to remove `\u001b[m\u001b[32m`

I added below setting in gsub for logstash but it still comes in Kibana
`["message","^\\u001b\[m\\u001b\[32m"," "]`

The code that I want to mutate is a color code used in tomcat to see info, error in tomcat logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to figure out color code , figured out a way around

```
mutate {
          gsub => ["message", ".+?(?=\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", "" 
       } 

Above GSUB mutate anything before Date. This resolved the issue
```